# How do I change a column name of a table in Confluence using alasql

Tags: rename, confluence, alasql

I have  multiple pages in Confluence, each with the same table with different content.
I want to collect all these tables into one table. This works.
Now I want to add the name of the pages into the first column. This works.
But, this column is called pages. I want it to be called Projects.

The underlying table might be expanded and therefore I do not know which nor how many columns the tables have. That is the reason why I use T1.*. I need all that columns that are there, but I want to leave out the Page column.

I am using the Table Transform, which enables me to write a SQL script.
The SQL syntax is ALASQl.

I tried the following, which gives another column called Projekt:

```
SELECT T1.'Page'AS Projekt, T1.* FROM T
```

But how do I remove column `Page`?
There is no rename in asasql in confluence.

Comment: The asterisk `T1.*` means "Select all columns From ...", but it looks as if you do not want all of them, at least not `Page` again

Comment: Thank you stefan, that is correct. The underlying table might be expanded and therefore I do not know which nor how many columns the tables have. That is the reason why I use T1.*. I need all that are there, but I want to leave out the Page column. Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes, your edited Question makes sense, I'd say and would not know an answer in the Standard SQL world. Perhaps except asking for the "XY problem" aspect, i.e. what for do you need the unknown number of unknown columns? Guessing that info could help to find something a like `Confluence` UI tweak or a subsequent `Alter Table` feature